# installing tizen studio 3.5 with jdk 10 how do you install?

Tags: tizen

I have downloaded tizen studio 3.5 and 3.2 as well as 10 jdks (open jdk8,9,10) oracle jdk(8,10,10.0.1,12,13) and set the Path variable to include the jdk\bin folder as well as the classpath and JAVA_HOME to point to this folder.The installer wont close on either 3.5 and 3.2 and the package manager wont run some jdks wont even run the installer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Specific versions** of JAVA are required for TizenStudio.

With OpenJDK it works fine. Just follow:
 https://developer.tizen.org/development/articles/openjdk-and-openjfx-installation-guide

Comment: I did all of that but still the install never finishes and the package manager never opens. I installed jdk 12 and 10.0.2 (if you notice on their page the examples are in 10 and they say 12).I filled the bin with javafx-sdk-11.0.2 and lib. I installed python set the path. It still tells me I need a jdk and packagemanagerV2 does nothing even though it loads.please help